# VideoCapture.Open Fails

Tags: c++, opencv, object, object-detection, detection

It always fails to open and it prints the thing thats in `if (!capVideo.isOpened())`, AND YES I am sure the path is correct

```
cv::VideoCapture capVideo;

capVideo.open("C:\\Users\\Eren\\Desktop\\vid.mp4");

if (!capVideo.isOpened()) { // if unable to open video file
    std::cout << "error reading video file" << std::endl << std::endl;  
    capVideo.open("C:\\Users\\Eren\\Desktop\\vid.mp4");// show error message
    _getch();  // it may be necessary to change or remove this line if not using Windows
    return(0);  // and exit program
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt those double slashes(/)  just one?

Comment: np, its the way of writing path

Comment: It would be helpful to include the error message in your post.